# Get multiply accordion sections to keep open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following accordion in my html:

```
<div id="AccordionTop">
 <div class="accordionTitle"><h1 style="font-size: 16px">Test Name:</h1></div>
 <div class="accordionContent">
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend ullamcorper tempus.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="accordionTitle"><h1 style="font-size: 16px">Test Name:</h1></div>
 <div class="accordionContent" style="border-color: #0a0a0a">
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend ullamcorper tempus.</p>
 </div>
```

My document ready function is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.accordionTitle').click(function() {

    $('.accordionTitle').removeClass('on');

    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }

});
```

});

When I open one of the accordion the other closes, I would like them to keep open until I manually close them. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.accordionTitle').click(function() {

         $('.accordionTitle').removeClass('on');

         $(this).next().slideUp('normal');

         if($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {

           $(this).addClass('on');

           $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
         }
     });
   });
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/qunujezeni/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I need to earn reputions

Comment: @ksup what about accepting the right answer? You will earn reputation for that!